# why is python giving me errors while trying to install a third party module, openpyxl version 2.6.1?

Tags: python, windows, error-handling, openpyxl

i am reading the book Automate the boring stuff with python by AI Sweigart. i am on the chapter working with excel spreadsheets, and the its telling me to download a specific version of openpyxl. but when i try to download it to gives me a error. i attach the errors i got, i cut come of it out because its very long it looks like its looking for a specific file?? why is this?? i tried two commands,
pip install --user openpyxl==2.6.1 and pip install openpyxl==2.6.1. but both commands give me the same error???

```
`C:\Users\JO>pip install openpyxl==2.6.1
 Collecting openpyxl==2.6.1
  Using cached openpyxl-2.6.1.tar.gz (173 kB)
  ERROR: Error [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file
 specified  while executing python setup.py egg_info
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
 ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError   2] The system cannot   find the file specified

--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\JO\AppData\Local\Packages \PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local- packages\Python310\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\logging.py",   line 177, in emit
 self.console.print(renderable, overflow="ignore", crop=False,  style=style)

---Snip---
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146).

Comment: [`openpyxl`](https://pypi.org/project/openpyxl/) is on version 3 now. 2.6.1 was released over 3 years ago. The code in your book should still work with the current version. Try `pip install -U --user openpyxl` and see if that works.

Comment: YES indeed it did work! thanks. wow didnt know i could use the current version!

Comment: Pretty often you can. It always makes sense to check the release notes in case there's been some breaking change, especially within major versions, but that doesn't happen *that* often.